# SharePoint 2013 & Caml & Membership

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-server

Can you use the membership element as part of a caml query for a view in a document library? I would like to show documents based on the group the current user is a member of? And I would like to avoid doing item level security..Please help

Comment: The CAML query will only fetch the data that the logged in user has access to! How are you planning to determine which documents must be presented to which group if you are planning not to use permissions?

Comment: I have a user group field called Department, which I populate with SharePoint groups in my code. The field allows for multiples, so I can have one or more site groups set into this field. Thank you so much for response..I have to get this code completed and shipped to production ASAP. Thank you again for your help.